# same mktime() result for different datetime string

Tags: c, datetime, glibc, mktime

I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm timeinfo;

    strptime( "2016-02-18 09:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo );
    printf( "result 1=%ld\n", mktime( &timeinfo ) );

    strptime( "2016-02-18 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo );
    printf( "result 2=%ld\n", mktime( &timeinfo ) );
}
```

The result for this MCVE drives me crazy:

```
result 1=1455778800
result 2=1455778800
```

1455778800 is the UTC time for `2016-02-18 07:00:00` so it would be correct for the 2nd datetime string. But why do I get for two different strings the same result?

And now this:

```
{
    struct tm timeinfo;

    strptime( "2016-02-18 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo );
    printf( "result 2=%ld\n", mktime( &timeinfo ) );
    strptime( "2016-02-18 09:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo );
    printf( "result 1=%ld\n", mktime( &timeinfo ) );
}
```

Here I have this result:

```
result 2=1455775200
result 1=1455782400
```

`result 1` is now correct but `result 2` is one hour too early. It looks like the internal `glibc` structures are not properly initialized when I call it the 1st time.

I am linking it with another `glibc` version than the system is using. When I link it with the system version then it works. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I can't replicate your result using clang 700.1.81 on OS X. I'm in a different time zone from you. You appear to be in Central European time? That could possibly maybe cause a problem. Try `timegm` instead of `mktime` to eliminate time zones as a possibility. Could you verify your time zone? Also you should print out `&timeinfo` manually to verify whether `strptime` or `mktime` is at fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the solution was in the `man` pages:

> In principle, this function does not initialize tm but stores only 
>   the values specified.  This means that tm should be initialized
>   before the call.  Details differ a bit between different UNIX
>   systems.  The glibc implementation does not touch those fields which
>   are not explicitly specified, except that it recomputes the tm_wday
>   and tm_yday field if any of the year, month, or day elements changed.

`bzero(&timeinfo, sizeof(timeinfo));` and now it works.

Comment: or `struct tm timeinfo = { 0 };`

Comment: @chux I am using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and this does not work for `gcc`. There are lot of "old" structures which I must initialize with `bzero()`

Comment: Many ways to zero data.  `bzero()` is better than trying to zero individual fields as the total field count of `struct tm` is not defined.  Good it works for you.